# Angular2 w/ Typescript - Client/Server App the right way?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm cutting my teeth on Angular2 (and Angular in general) getting the core concepts under my belt and have been working on my first "real" application. I'm using some sample projects on GitHub and the quickstart on the Angular site as guides but have run into some roadblocks and am looking for some advice on the "right" way to set up the directory structure, integrate typings and reference node modules in the application. Obviously some aspects would be personal coding preference so I'm just out here fishing for some best practices advice.

Application Overview:

- Application has a server-side component used to connect to a local SQL server and brokers calls from the client side to provide data to be displayed.
- Application has a client-side component used to serve pages/template and communicate with the server-side to make calls to retrieve data and display it on the page
- Application uses gulp to configure and launch both the server and the client side (different calls - eg: gulp start-server / gulp start-client)

I have the basics of all of the working so my question isn't really about that. My issues come up when I have node modules that I need to leverage and what is the right way / best way to integrate those.

Lets say my basic directory structure is like this (based on sample projects I'm using as references)...

```
- client
  |- public
     |- app
     |- css
     |- lib (some js files)
     |- etc...
     index.html
  |- typings
  client.ts/js

- node_modules
  |- modules installed via npm install

- server
  |- core (contains db-connection)
  |- typings
  server.ts/js
```

Now, lets say I needed and installed the node module Rxjs and need to reference it in my client-side...this is where things are getting unclear for me.

I've seen some postings that I should be using the "map" feature of System.config to map to the node_module in conjunction with the packages feature in the index.html file, but I am unable to get that to work. The app launches, but the client side app component doesn't appear to be able to see it. It's almost like an out-of-scope issue. (Sorry, I do not have the exact error message handy). If I use map, am I allowed/supposed to map it to its home in the node_modules directory or should I be putting the needed typescript files within the directory structure of Public?

I've also seen some postings where you can just move the js file to say the lib directory and reference it as a javascript src file in index.html...but I'm getting no joy there either.

I believe that part of the issue is likely ties to requires/dependencies within the various node_modules themselves, but I'm not sure how to deal with that.

So, what is the right/best way to set this all up and integrate the node_modules that I need? Is it simply not possible to reference modules within the node_modules from a client-side app and I need to bring all of the .d.ts/ts/js files into the public scope? If so, do I need to investigate the references within each ts file and bring everything over?

I understand that I may not be providing all or perfectly specific details here, but I hope you can see the higher-level best-practices question that I'm posing here and push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone setting up Typescript with Angular 2 and SystemJS.

I assume you have the basic setup working (if not, let me know). I usually don't touch modules after `npm install`. This is how I set it up (using Angular 2 and jQuery as examples):

1. For **Angular 2**, install the necessary modules listed in the package.json at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html
2. In your `public/ts/main.ts` (whichever has the `bootstrap()` function), put a reference to the type definition: `/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />`
3. This will allow you to `import ... from 'angular2/core'` assuming you've set up SystemJS properly. My SystemJS config:

   ```
   System.config({
     packages: {
       js: {format: 'register'}
     }
   });
   System.import('/js/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
   ```
4. For **jQuery** (and others), `npm install jquery` and `typings install jquery --ambient` (unlike Angular 2 the type definitions are in a separate repo).
5. Again, find and reference the type definition in `public/ts/main.ts`:
   `/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/index.d.ts" />`
6. There are 2 ways to load the actual jQuery code.
   1) `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>` in `index.html`
   Now you can just use `$` in your Angular 2 code. Type checking should work as expected. (Don't use `import * as $ from 'jquery'` since SystemJS will make a GET request to `/jquery` which may or may not exist).
   2) If you want to load jQuery from your `node_modules/`, you'll need an extra bit of setup: In your backend, you need to serve you're `node_modules/` directory. In ExpressJS, you can do this using:

   ```
   app.use(express.static(PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER + '/node_modules'));
   ```

   Then you need to tell SystemJS to make a GET request to the `jquery.js` file inside your `node_modules/` instead of just `/jquery`. Do this by using `map`:

   ```
   System.config({
     map: {
       jquery: '/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
     },
     packages: {
       js: {format: 'register'}
     }
   });
   System.import('/js/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
   ```

   This means every time you `import * as $ from 'jquery';` in your code, SystemJS will make the GET request to `/jquery/dist/jquery.js` instead of `/jquery`, which is what we want.
   Now just `import * as $ from 'jquery'` wherever you need it and things should work.
7. You can do the above steps for other modules (lodash, etc.), assuming they have a proper type definition and work inside a browser.

For a sample, you can look at my boilerplate https://github.com/simonxca/mean2-boilerplate. It's a MEAN stack and doesn't contain everything here, but it might be helpful. Hope it goes well.